# HiddenInput Attribute Missing in System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

Tags: class, asp.net-mvc-4, model, data-annotations

I have a domain model in a DLL that I want to keep *separate* from my main ASP.NET MVC project.

I want to decorate the properties in this model with metadata attributes (such as DisplayName, UIHint, DataType, etc.).  This is so that I can call **EditorForModel** to have these properties properly rendered in my ASP.NET MVC View.

Most of the attributes are available in the namespace **System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations** but to my surprise, **[HiddenInput]** is NOT part of this namespace.  It seems that **[HiddenInput]** is only in **System.Web.Mvc** (which I cannot reference from my stand-alone domain model DLL).

My domain model is in its own separate DLL class, and I don't want to move it inside my ASP.NET MVC project.

What other solutions do I have if I want to flag certain attributes in this model as "hidden" so that **EditorForModel** can recognize it (and hide it) when rendering the view?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the UiHintAttribute that resides in the DataAnnotations namespace

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.uihintattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

```
[UIHint("Hidden")]
public int ID { get; set; }
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your response, @Slicksim.

Will EditorForModel be able to recognize **[UIHint("Hidden")]** and hide the field when rendering the view?

Comment: If you use the mvc standard template, I.e. dont provide a template it will. If you use editorfor in your own template, it will use the uihint to output the hidden

Comment: I used Editable(false)